# Clear app data programatically doesnt work

Tags: android, appdata, app-data

I have a button "Logout", and after click them i want to clear all data and cache of app. I found in similar topics in this site methods to delete data:

```
   public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if(appDir.exists()){
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for(String s : children){
            if(!s.equals("lib")){
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

But when i use the code:

```
logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           clearApplicationData();
           finish();
           startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
       }
      });
```

my app restarts, but app data doesnt delete. So, how to delete programatically all cache and data of app?

Comment: "but app data doesnt delete" -- how did you determine this?

Comment: data in database didnt delete. shared preferences value doesnt delete...

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, every step you took to determine that "data in database didnt delete. shared preferences value doesnt delete". For example, did you comment out `startActivity()`, then look to see if the actual files are gone? Perhaps your new `MainActivity` instance is showing some data that you have cached in memory.

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(V1_KEY, "someValue");
        editor.apply();
then
 clearApplicationData();
finish();
Intent i = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
and after than i get the value
preferences.getString(V1_KEY, null);
and obtain "someValue" instead of null ...

Answer (score 1):

First, your code does not necessarily delete the file where `SharedPreferences` are stored. Its location is undocumented, IIRC, and it does not necessarily have to be in the scope of what you are deleting.

Second, `SharedPreferences` are cached in your process. Even if you do successfully delete the file, the cached `SharedPreferences` will not know that you deleted it. Until your process terminates, you will continue to have access to the "deleted" `SharedPreferences` data.

If your objective is to be able to delete data, only store data in places that you control, and where you control how that data gets cached. Replace your use of `SharedPreferences` with something else (e.g., SQLite database, or some file that you manage yourself).